# Count occurrences across different columns with the same information

Tags: count, stata

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
ID S1 S2 S3 year
1  1  2     1999
1  1  2     2000
2  1        1999
2  1        2000
3  1        1999
3  2        2000
4  1  2  3  1999
4  3  1  2  2000
5  1  2     1999
5  1  3     2000
```

where the first column is the subject ID, `S1` to `S3` are location identifiers and year refers to either 1999 or 2000. I would like to count all the occurrences in which a subject stays in the same location in both years (using Stata). That is, for subject 1, this value is 2, for subject 2, it is 1, for subject 3 it is 0, for subject 4 it is 3 and for subject 5 it is 1.

Comment: Spelling has been Stata for >30 years. Column is just spreadsheet jargon: to Stata these are variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your blanks are really numeric missing. This should also work if `S1 S2 S3` are in fact string and the blanks are empty strings. The example that 1 2 3 and 3 1 2 are equivalent rules out various simpler solutions of just counting similarities over `S1 S2 S3` in a loop.

```
clear 
input ID S1 S2 S3 year
1  1  2  .  1999
1  1  2  .  2000
2  1  .  .  1999
2  1  .  .  2000
3  1  .  .  1999
3  2  .  .  2000
4  1  2  3  1999
4  3  1  2  2000
5  1  2  .  1999
5  1  3  .  2000
end 

reshape long S, i(ID year) j(which) 
bysort ID (S) : gen count = sum(S == S[_n-1] & !missing(S)) 
by ID: replace count = count[_N] 
reshape wide S, i(ID year) j(which)  

list, sepby(ID) 

     +----------------------------------+
     | ID   year   S1   S2   S3   count |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. |  1   1999    1    2    .       2 |
  2. |  1   2000    1    2    .       2 |
     |----------------------------------|
  3. |  2   1999    1    .    .       1 |
  4. |  2   2000    1    .    .       1 |
     |----------------------------------|
  5. |  3   1999    1    .    .       0 |
  6. |  3   2000    2    .    .       0 |
     |----------------------------------|
  7. |  4   1999    1    2    3       3 |
  8. |  4   2000    3    1    2       3 |
     |----------------------------------|
  9. |  5   1999    1    2    .       1 |
 10. |  5   2000    1    3    .       1 |
     +----------------------------------+
```